# Issues trying to webscrap in C#

Tags: c#, web-scraping, web, post

I am currently trying to webscrap some entries from a table of a website but when I make the get request, the string response does not include those entries that are shown in the website.

Here is the website: https://www.services-rte.com/en/view-data-published-by-rte/downtime-of-generation-resources.html

My guess is that I need to make a Post request to load the table but I can't find exactly what to post. Correct me if I am wrong.

Here is my code

```
static async void GetEntries()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddHttpClient();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
        var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

        string response = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.services-rte.com/en/view-data-published-by-rte/downtime-of-generation-resources.html");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Site not found.");
            return;
        }

        var parser = new HtmlParser();
        var document = parser.ParseDocument(response);

        string content = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                content = document.QuerySelector($"#wrapper > div > div > div.c-editorial-page__container > div.c-editorial-page__content > ctx-remit-generation-unavailability > cortex-remit-generation-unavailability-table > cortex-table > div > div.ctx__table_content > cortex-table-row:nth-child({i})").TextContent;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"CSS selector not found for {i}.");
                continue;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(content);
            Console.WriteLine("NEW");
        }
    }
```

Error in this line: content = document.QuerySelector($"#wrapper > div > div > div.c-editorial-page__container > div.c-editorial-page__content > ctx-remit-generation-unavailability > cortex-remit-generation-unavailability-table > cortex-table > div > div.ctx__table_content > cortex-table-row:nth-child({i})").TextContent;

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: That table is being generated by another call to get JSON, sounds like it would be much easier if you do the same, just GET this page (with dynamic query string of course): https://www.services-rte.com/api/public/generation_unavailability?start_date=2023-02-01&end_date=2023-03-01&status=ACTIVE&unavailability_type=PLANNED_MAINTENANCE

Comment: I am aware the api exists but I specifically want to webscrap the data. Can't I call the function that is generating the table?

Comment: No, that is Javascript

Comment: @MegaPaul: Web scraping is an exercise in reverse-engineering.  Ideally you would be able to interact with an API instead.  But if that's not available then you're at the mercy of whatever functionality builds that page in the browser.  You can use your browser's debugging tools to observe the interactions that page makes with the server and attempt to replicate that functionality.  You can also try using a "headless browser" which includes a full browser engine in code, to execute JavaScript and whatnot on the page and render the result in memory.

Comment: @MegaPaul: *"I am aware the api exists but I specifically want to webscrap the data."* - Why?  For what purpose?  If your goal is to get the data then **that's how you get the data**.  If your goal is to practice scraping a page then choose a page that includes data.

Comment: alright, how did you find the function or the js that generates the table btw?

Comment: @MegaPaul: Open your browser's developer/debugging tools and observe the requests/responses on the Network tab.

Comment: there is like hundreds of scripts here how did you distinguish the right one?

Comment: @MegaPaul: If something is being dynamically generated then my first step would be to go to the Network tab, filter for AJAX (HXR) requests, and look through them to find data which looks like what's in that table.  Of course there's no guarantee that's where to find it.  Again, you're at the mercy of how any given website is designed.  And any given website could very well be designed in a way that's prohibitively difficult to scrape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the data is loaded async? I mean the table on the website. I had this problem once: I did see the HTML on the website, but when I did a request via C# I couldn't find the HTML.

What you can do is use something like **Selenium**. I know this might not be the best answer because I cannot really show you how to use it, but there is a plugin of Selenium you can use in C#. This can work with websites that load data async.

Maybe this website can help you: https://www.scrapingdog.com/blog/web-scraping-with-csharp/ (not mine, but it looks promising).